# Mod_rewrite flat links

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, hyperlink, flat

I'm trying to display my get variables as flat links.
Want to change from this:

```
http://mydomain.com/index.php?page=shop&var1=hat&var2=10
```

to

```
http://mydomain.com/index.php/shop/hat/10
```

Please keep in mind that there isn't a fixed number of variables, that's why I use var1,var2,...etc

[edit]
I already have a partially working script, but works only with max 3 variables

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule .* - [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&var=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?([^/\.]+)/?([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&var=$2&var2=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?([^/\.]+)/?([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&var=$2&var2=$3&var3=$4 [L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first remember mod_rewrite works like this :

```
http://mydomain.com/index.php/shop/hat/10
```

(what the client type) is rewritten to

```
http://mydomain.com/index.php?page=shop&var1=hat&var2=10
```

(what the client is served), but not necessarily displayed like the latter. (Unless you make it a redirect)

So assuming your format is completly described here :

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)$ /index.php?page=$1&var2=$2&var2=$3
```

Should be good.

**EDIT:**

Oh BTW! I did not take the variable number of variable into account. That should not be processed by mod_rewrite I think. Maybe the best shot is to `RewriteRule index.php/(.*) /index.php?call=$1` and then use your script to explode using / delimiter.

You can only do it if you already know the number of variable only AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Your script looks good and looks like it should work but it gives me "object not found". Maybe I'm missing something, here is my implementation of your code <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index\.php/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)$ /index.php?page=$1&var2=$2&var2=$3
</IfModule>. The website is in testing mode and is not in the root of the domain

Comment: Ah! My rules only work if your index.php is in the root. Did you try to add the directory link before index.php?

Comment: This works like you intended in the second solution ^(.*)?$ index.php?page=$1 [L] .Didn't work with the index.php or with the directory. It's good enough for me. Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

You could just direct all request directly to index.php (called bootstrapping), and let the script parse out the variables.

This is how it's done with [Zend Framework](http://zendframework.com), you should take a look at it. ZF also has loads of other goodies you could utilize.

This is my rewrite block from one of my vhosts with a ZF powered website.

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}      !^/favicon.ico
    RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```