# .htaccess RewriteRule for Flat Links

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am pretty new to using the RewriteRule, so I am likely missing something obvious, but I have a PHP script that takes URL variables like this:

```
{baseurl}properties.php?prop=Property-Name
```

I would like to create RewriteRules so that anyone who types in this script name/variable combo would have their URL rewritten to:

```
{baseurl}/properties/Property-Name
```

As well as ensuring that anyone who types in the flat-link url, actually calls the script with the right variable name and value.

I have been referring to [this link](http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php) and I have found related threads:

[Mod_rewrite flat links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5660283/mod-rewrite-flat-links)

[Mod_rewrite trouble: Want to direct from ?= to a flat link, nothing seems to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4718652/mod-rewrite-trouble-want-to-direct-from-to-a-flat-link-nothing-seems-to-work)

But, I am obviously doing something wrong, as I cannot get this URL to work the way I want. I am currently using the following code, which appears to do nothing (aside from rewriting the URL to include the www, and redirect requests for index.php to the site root):

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^baseurl.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.baseurl.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index.php / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^properties/([0-9A-Za-z]+)/$ /properties.php?prop=$1
```

The issue is clearly with the last RewriteRule, assuming nothing above is affecting it. Again, I am likely doing something ridiculous. Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a quick glance, it appears that you forgot to include the dash in your regular expression and you included trailing slash. Use this instead:

```
RewriteRule ^properties/([0-9A-Za-z-]+)$ /properties.php?prop=$1
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you. That allows me to access my script using the {baseurl}/properties/property-name URL. Now, I need to ensure that typing out the full script name with URL variables gets re-written to the flat link URL.

Comment: @DaveL - If you end the line above with `[QSA,L]`, it'll rewrite the query string parameters too (i.e. /properties/property-name?id=123 would become /properties.php?prop=property-name&id=123).

Comment: Thanks again, but I'm afraid I haven't made myself clear - I want to keep the script name and query string parameters transparent. Even if the user knows enough to type the absolute path to the script, and provide the necessary query string parameters, I would like my .htaccess to rewrite/redirect the URL to the flat link format. I have a few things to try before I admit defeat on this one. I may start another thread if I get stumped. Thanks again.

Comment: @DaveL - So you want the user redirected? In that case, you'd want to include `[R=302]` at the end of the line. If you want to include query string parameters, as in my previous reply, you could do `[QSA,R=302]`.

Comment: Heh. I've determined the source of our confusion here. I am actually asking for RewriteRules that would generate a redirect loop. My mistake. I will have to deal with what I have. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at your rule `^properties/([0-9A-Za-z]+)/$` you see that it needs to end with a forward slash. You can either remove that or make it optional like `^properties/([0-9A-Za-z]+)/?$`.

Comment: Your answer was useful too, but sadly, I am too new to upvote it, and I can't have more than one accepted answer. You have my thanks, sir.