# Writing .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to develop site on php and mysql, at this moment i'm 50% done with php coding, though I don't know almost anything about php programming :). Now I'm stuck in url structure for my site.

My sites root directory is localhost/mysite and when I going to a article page I have 
localhost/mysite/article**.php?title=**any-article-title
I want to change this slug in to 
localhost/mysite/article/any-article-title

I saw an exact similar thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429102/htaccess-rewriterule-for-flat-links) but I cant implement that answer to my site.

Any help will be highly appreciated

One more thing I would like to add - Is there any global rule to do the same for all files like article.php?title= or product.php?item= or category.php?id=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The possible problem that you may be facing here is the way how you accessing to your site: `localhost/mysite/...` This can make perfectly valid rewrite rule not to work (based on other configuration parameters/circumstances). It will be better if you could set up your website to be accessible via dedicated domain name (which you can easily fake via `hosts` file) -- so that you can access your local website via `http://mysite.dev/index.php` instead of the current `http://localhost/mysite.com/index.php`.

Anyway -- these are the rules:

```
# activate rewrite engine
RewriteEngine On
# treat /mysite/ as a root
RewriteBase /mysite/

# rewrite "localhost/mysite/article/some-title" into "localhost/mysite/article.php?title=some-title"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule article/(.+)$ article.php?title=$1 [QSA,L]
```

You can do the rest (`product.php?item=` or `category.php?id=`) in a similar fashion.

Comment: @lazyOne Thank you very very very much. U r a life saver for me. I'm working on this for last 20 hrs or more. Finally your script worked for me. thank you very much again!!

Comment: @lazyOne though I'm done with your help, would you like to explain this three lines RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule article/(.+)$ article.php?title=$1 [QSA,L] not much just little bit will be great

Comment: @Anuj First 2 lines tell to only do rewrite if requested URL is not a file or directory (it is possible that you may actually have a real file in `/article/` folder on your server). If such extra check is not required, you can remove those 2 lines. Last line s actually a rule which tells Apache which URLs and how they need to be rewritten. I cannot explain this in few words -- you need to have some background and be familiar with how this idea works in general and know regular expression syntax a bit. You can read more on this page: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/

Comment: @LazyOne Well! learned something I must say. Thanks again :) By the way I deleted those first two lines as I don't need them. One last request is can you tell me what the last part [QSA, L] does?

Comment: @Anuj http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html `QSA` (Query String Append) will add existing query string to new/rewritten URL. Useful when you passing other parameters (like, campaign/referral id etc). `L` (Last) tells Apache to stop rewriting on this rule (if it matches, of course).

Comment: @LazyOne you are a genius and a great helpful man(I think). I never seen so helpful and kind community member anywhere.

Comment: @LazyOne can you reply one more time please? I now need a little different redirection. Now I'm redirecting abc.dev/category/any-thing to abc.dev/category.php?category=any-thing, I just need to redirect abc.dev/category/any-thing/?page=4 should be redirected to abc.dev/category.php?category=any-thing&page=4

Comment: @LazyOne I'm not sure if I made my self clear so I'm adding this - I want to put RewriteRule article/"any-thing-here/"(.+)$ article.php?title=$1 [QSA,L] in this line you wrote above. I cant put the write syntax there and so it is not working.

Comment: @Anuj You better ask this a separate question (that's for the future). Any way -- copy 2 RewriteCond lines and add this below: `RewriteRule category/(.+)/$ category.php?category=$1 [QSA,L]`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^article/(.*)$ article.php?title=$1 [L]
```

for multiple handlers try something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ router.php?type=$1&title=$2 [L]
```

router.php is there to make sure that you will address only allowed files (e.g. caregory.php, product.php and article.php) and prevent users to access any sensitive files using URLs like /config/blablabla.

Comment: @Anuj just to be sure - you have mod_rewrite installed and running, right ?

you may also try ^article/(.*)$ /article.php?title=$1  (with / before article.php)

Comment: @Sergey Nester yes I have. I'm using wamp on localhost and mod_rewrite module is on. I'm running a Wordpress site on the web and it is installed on localhost/wp directory also. mod_rewrite is working fine for it but I cant get it worked for this :(

Comment: @Anuj - and what exactly problem is, article.php is not opening or it is opening but does not receive slug ?

Comment: I pasted the exact code you wrote but and when I browse my site it still has the same url format article.php?title=anything. If i manually delete the article.php?title=anything it gives nothing found page

Comment: @Anuj - of course URLs will remain same - you need to change them manually. .htaccess only works with other side of the problem - when somebody requests /article/bla-bla-bla/ page .htaccess redirects request to the article.php?title=bla-bla-bla

Comment: @Sergey Why do you need all these `RewriteCond`? They are actually wrong.

Comment: @LazyOne - Ouch, my bad, fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

http://www.freewebmasterhelp.com/tutorials/htaccess/2

Will teach you how to configure and what to write for each redirection

EDIT: I suppose you need to do individually for all the files

Comment: thank you for your so fast reply. But I'm still nowhere there.  Can you please write the exact one line for me please