# how to write rewrite rule in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.htaccess RewriteRule for Flat Links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429102/htaccess-rewriterule-for-flat-links)

i have a problem in a rewrite rule

i want a url like this

```
www.mysite.com/category/funny
```

how my actual looks like is this

```
www.mysite.com/category.php?cate=funny
```

What will be the rewrite rule for that?

Comment: i tried something like this but didnt work
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/category/?$   category.php?cate=$1

Comment: Have you also tried the search? Because questions like this come up weekly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That should do it:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^category/([^/\.]+)/?$ category.php?cate=$1 [L]
```

Comment: You may accept the answer and vote it up if you wish ;P

Comment: yup i cant vote up i have only 13 reputation but i accepted the ans.